# Adding properties to existing TypeScript interface via module augmentation has no effect

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typescript-definitions, typescript-declarations

I have a Node application that depends on [`@types/hapi`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/hapi).  I'd like to add a property to one of the classes defined in this module.  I've tried defining my new property via module augmentation:

```
// my-custom-hapi-typings.d.ts
import * as hapi from 'hapi';

declare module hapi {
    interface Server {
        myProperty: string;
    }
}
```

This doesn't cause any compiler errors, but it also doesn't add the `myProperty` property to the `Server` class.  I still get errors elsewhere in my project when I try and reference the property like this:

```
// my-other-file.ts
import * as hapi from 'hapi';

const server = new hapi.Server({ ... });

// error: Property 'myProperty' does not exist on type 'Server'.
server.myProperty = 'hello';
```

Why does the TypeScript compiler seem to be ignoring my `.d.ts` file?  Do I need to "import" the file or somehow make the TypeScript compiler aware that this file exists?  I was under the impression that just placing a `.d.ts` file in the source directory was enough for TypeScript to pick up on these augmentations.

Comment: The top-level `import` makes the file a module. Try removing it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Aaron, but I just tried removing the top-level `import` and the result is the same.

Comment: Try putting "hapi" in quotes: `declare module "hapi"`. You might also need to `export` the `Server` interface.

Comment: @Aaron - putting `'hapi'` in quotes fixed the issue!  Thanks!  Not sure I understand why though.  If you want to add your comment as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Sure, I'll try to explain in answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your issue:

```
declare module hapi {
```

This is actually defining a [`namespace`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html), using older syntax that pre-dates ES6 modules which used to be called "internal modules". Writing `module hapi` is the same as writing `namespace hapi`, which is the preferred syntax today. [More on namespaces vs modules here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html)

To [declare an external module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries) you just have to put the module name in quotes:

> [...] use a construct similar to ambient namespaces, but we **use the `module` keyword and the quoted name** of the module which will be available to a later import.

In other words, just put `hapi` in quotes:

```
declare module "hapi"
```

Now you have an *ambient* (`my-custom-hapi-typings.d.ts` doesn't need to be directly imported) *external module* definition (declares what `import "hapi"` gives you), and you can augment whats declared inside it.

If you mouse over the `module hapi` and `module "hapi"` [in the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20module%20hapi%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Adeclare%20module%20%22hapi%22%20%7B%20%7D) you'll see the difference in the tooltips:

[image]
[image]

Yes, it's subtle and confusing due the history behind it.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, @Aaron.  Although the only change I needed to make was wrapping `'hapi'` in quotes.  If I remove the `import` statement, my declaration seems like it is *overwriting* the `hapi` module definition instead of *augmenting* it - the only properties I can access are ones that I define myself.  So I think the `import` statement is necessary for augmentation.

Comment: @NathanFriend Hm, you're right. I think its actually a top-level `export` that makes it a module, or else being a module doesn't actually change the effect of `declare module "hapi"`. You can also import inside the module declaration. I'll edit my answer... don't want this answer to mislead anyone. :)